# NSISdl timeout on perfectly fine link

Tags: download, nsis

So, I'm making a sort-of web installer. It gets to the part where it says "Connecting..." and then simply just waits a while.. then fails because of a timeout.

Script for it is here.

```
NSISdl::download "https://www.dropbox.com/s/b65bvezj2u58872/ns_fwl_byps.dll?dl=1" "$INSTDIR\ns_fwl_byps.dll"
  Pop $R0 ;Get the return value
  StrCmp $R0 "success" +3
    MessageBox MB_OK "Download failed: $R0"
    Quit
```

The link works perfectly fine in a web browser.

Preferably I would like to use NSISdl, so I'd like a workaround for this problem rather than suggesting another plugin.

Comment: Is it a public file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSISdl does not support HTTPS, use [Inetc](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Inetc_plug-in)...

(NSISdl works all the way back to Win95 and just uses plain sockets, Inetc uses WinInet like Internet Explorer)